# Ansible how to loop with_dict

Tags: ansible

I want to run these mikrotik commands using ansible

```
interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether3
interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether4
```

BUT NOT

```
interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether3,ether4
```

my playbook run wrong command
How to fix that
tq

### `# cat main.yml

```
- hosts: mikrotiks
  gather_facts: no
  connection: network_cli
  vars:
  ansible_network_os: routeros
  vlans:
  - 10:
    interfaces:
      - ether3
      - ether4
    untagged_interfaces: ether2
    tagged_interfaces: bridge1,ether3,ether4
    network: 10.0.10.0
    netmask: 24
    ip_address1: 10.0.10.1
    ip_address2: 10.0.10.2
    dns: 192.168.88.1
    dhcp_pool1: 10.0.10.101-10.0.10.150
    dhcp_pool2: 10.0.10.151-10.0.10.200
    leasetime: 1d
  - 20:
    interfaces:
      - ether3
      - ether4
    untagged_interfaces: ether2
    tagged_interfaces: bridge1,ether3,ether4
    network: 10.0.20.0
    netmask: 24
    ip_address1: 10.0.20.1
    ip_address2: 10.0.20.2
    dns: 192.168.88.1
    dhcp_pool1: 10.0.20.101-10.0.20.150
    dhcp_pool2: 10.0.20.151-10.0.20.200
    leasetime: 1d
    tasks:
  - import_tasks: vlan.yml
```

## cat vlan.yml

---

```
- name: create vlans on R1
  routeros_command:
  commands:
    - "interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface={{ item.value.interfaces }}"
    - "interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 frame-types=admit-only-untagged-and-priority-tagged pvid=10 interface={{ item.value.interfaces }}"
  with_dict: "{{ vlans }}"\`
```

EDIT: my mikrotik commands should be like this
`R1 /interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether3 add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether4 add bridge=bridge1 frame-types=admit-only-untagged-and-priority-tagged interface=ether2 pvid=10 /interface bridge vlan add bridge=bridge1 tagged=bridge1,ether3,ether4 untagged=ether2 vlan-ids=10 add bridge=bridge1 tagged=bridge1,ether3,ether4 vlan-ids=20`

when I use these

```
\`routeros_command:
commands:
  - "/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface={{ item.1 }}"
  - "/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 frame-types=admit-only-untagged-and-priority-tagged pvid=10 interface={{ item.1 }}"
```

with_subelements:
- "{{ vlans }}"
- interfaces`

I got this error
`fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {
"msg": "could not find 'interfaces' key in iterated item '{10: {'interfaces': ['ether3', 'ether4'], 'untagged_interfaces': 'ether2', 'tagged_interfaces': 'bridge1,ether3,ether4', 'network': '10.0.10.0', 'netmask': 24, 'ip_address1': '10.0.10.1', 'ip_address2': '10.0.10.2', 'dns': '192.168.88.1', 'dhcp_pool1': '10.0.10.101-10.0.10.150', 'dhcp_pool2': '10.0.10.151-10.0.10.200', 'leasetime': '1d'}}'"`

Comment: you dont explain your logic, you have twice time ether3 and ether4, what is the right record, always the first or you want to group all interfaces and just keep distinct????

Comment: I want my playbook run these commands
`interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether3
interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether4`
but my playbook run this instead
`interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface=ether3,ether4`
I am sure my playbook wrong

Comment: if I modify like this
- name: create vlans on R1
  routeros_command:
    commands:
      - "/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ingress-filtering=no interface={{ item.value.interfaces }}"
      - "/interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 frame-types=admit-only-untagged-and-priority-tagged pvid=10 interface={{ item.value.interfaces }}"
  loop: "{{ vlans|subelements('interfaces')}}"

if I give that, it will error
fatal: [R1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "could not find 'interfaces' key in iterated item {10: {'interfaces': ['ether3', 'ether4'], '

Comment: you didnt answer to my question.....

Comment: @frenchy sorry for my bad english.
from main.yml I have 2 vlans (vlan10,20). each vlan have 2 nics ether3,ether4
what I want is run these command once
commands:
    - "interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ... interface=ether3
    - "interface bridge port add bridge=bridge1 ... interface=ether4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate *with_subelements*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.keys()|first }} ... interface={{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ vlans }}"
        - interfaces
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 10 ... interface=ether3
  msg: 10 ... interface=ether4
  msg: 20 ... interface=ether3
  msg: 20 ... interface=ether4
```